# export a csv from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv, export

I have two collections in my mongodb namely

1.companies

2.contacts

Both the companies and contact collection are interlinked. I want to export a particular companies contact into a csv. I have tried a mongo export command as follows

```
 mongoexport --csv -d dbname -c contacts 
 -q {"employment_details.company_id":ObjectId("50926cff9fe3125819006dc7")}; 
 -f {"first_name","last_name","title"} -o export.csv
```

I get a error as follows

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did u try looking into the mongodb [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/)

Comment: @AbhayKumar yes from that only i found about mongo export.

Comment: can you please paste some of your data form the collection

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There could be a couple of things going on here.  First, are you running `mongoexport` from the command line or from the `mongo` shell?  The `mongoexport` command is run from the command line.

Secondly, you need to properly format the query and field parameters.  You could enclose the  query with single quotes, and the filed name is not a JSON document, but just a list of fields.

This would look like the following from the command line:

```
mongoexport --csv -d dbname -c contacts -q '{"employment_details.company_id":ObjectId("50926cff9fe3125819006dc7")}' -f "first_name","last_name","title" -o export.csv
```

Comment: assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: '{employme..I got this error

Comment: what version are you using?  Exporting a sample document with 2.2.1 returns no errors.  Could you post a sample document - I've guessed at the structure in the format that is suggested by your command, but I could be incorrect.

Comment: I've just tried with 2.0.6 and also not seeing an error.  Could you post the document you get from `db.contacts.find({"employment_details.company_id":ObjectId("50926cff9fe3125819006dc7")})` when you try it from the mongo shell?

Comment: thanks @andre de Frere I got the answer. I missed the backslash before double quotes

Comment: mongoexport --csv -d dbname -c contacts --query {\"employment_details.company_id\":ObjectId(\"50926cff9fe3125819006dc7\")} -f "first_name,last_name,title" -o export.csv

Comment: "First, are you running mongoexport from the command line or from the mongo shell? The mongoexport command is run from the command line."  Thanks @AndredeFrere, that was my problem!  I was assuming from here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/ that you would run mongoexport from the mongo shell, because that same page mentions things like clone and copyDatabase, which ARE run from the mongo shell. Running from the command line works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following query will work if it is running from commandLine

```
mongoexport -h host -d dbname -c contacts --csv -q '{"employment_details.company_id":ObjectId("50926cff9fe3125819006dc7")}' -f first_name,last_name,title -o export.csv
```